# How do I pass a bearer token when doing a next.js 13 server component data fetch?

Tags: next.js, firebase-authentication, next.js13

I have a bearer token that I get from client side Firebase auth which is saved in AuthContext. Note, it's `"use client"`:

```
// packages/webapp/src/context/AuthContext.tsx
"use client"
import React, { useEffect, useState, createContext, useContext, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { onAuthStateChanged, User, getAuth, getIdToken } from 'firebase/auth';
import firebaseApp from '@/lib/firebase';

const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

interface IAuthContext {
  user: User | null;
  token: string | null;
}

export const AuthContext = createContext<IAuthContext>({ user: null, token: null });

export const useAuthContext = (): IAuthContext => useContext(AuthContext);

interface IAuthContextProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export const AuthContextProvider: React.FC<IAuthContextProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
        const userToken = await getIdToken(user, true);
        setToken(userToken);
      } else {
        setUser(null);
        setToken(null);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, token }}>
      {loading ? <div>Loading authentication...</div> : children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

My page is:

```
// packages/webapp/src/app/(authenticated)/conversations/@list/page.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { List, Box, TextField, IconButton, Typography, Divider } from '@mui/material';
import AddCircleOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AddCircleOutline';
import ConversationListPreview from '../_components/ConversationListPreview';

const getConversations = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/conversations?limit=3`, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  });
}

export default async function ConversationListPage() {
  const conversations = await getConversations();

  return (
    <>
      <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <Box display="flex" justifyContent="flex-start" mb={2}>
          <Typography variant="h6">Conversations</Typography>
          <IconButton color="primary">
            <AddCircleOutlineIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Box>
        <TextField variant="outlined" fullWidth placeholder="Search..." size='small' />
      </Box>
      <List sx={{ width: '100%', overflow: 'auto' }}>
        {conversations && conversations.map((conversation, index) => (
          <>
            <ConversationListPreview key={`conversation-${conversation.id}`} conversation={conversation} />
            {(index < (conversations.length - 1)) && <Divider />}
          </>
        ))}
      </List>
    </>
  );
};
```

I want to do the fetch but pass a bearer token. How would I get that?